# How can I remap the arrow buttons in insert mode when Pencil is enabled

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode

I use vim to write text, and that’s why I often use it in combination with the Pencil plugin. The plugin creates significant delay in the movement of the cursor when in insert mode. I have tried to remap the arrow keys to quit the insert mode before moving the cursor, but this does not seem to work for up and down arrows as long as Pencil is enabled. Is there any way to override Pencil’s key bindings in this case, or any way to speed up the cursor movement when in insert mode?